# Cant' add items into a Spinner

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, spinner, addition, runtimeexception

I'm trying to add a list into a Spinner but I'm always getting an exception in LogCat saying:

```
"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{....}: java.lang.NullPointerException"
```

In the emulator, a dialog comes up saying that the application has stopped unexpectedly and I need to Force Close. I've tried different things, but I'm still getting the same exception.

Here's the code for the Activity:

```
public class CreateListActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{   
    Spinner categorySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.category_Spinner);

    CategoryAction categoryAction = new CategoryAction(getBaseContext());
    ArrayList<ListCategory> categorylist = new ArrayList<ListCategory>();
    ArrayList<String> categoryNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Get all existing categories.
    try
    {
        categorylist = (ArrayList<ListCategory>) categoryAction.getAllCategories();
    }

    catch(SQLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    // Add all existing category names. This will be used to add options to the spinner.
    for (ListCategory category : categorylist)
    {
        categoryNames.add(category.getCategoryName());
    }


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categoryNames);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.createlist);

    categorySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);    

    View addNewListButton = findViewById(R.id.Add_List_button);
    addNewListButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) 
{
    ListAction listAction = new ListAction(getBaseContext());

    EditText listEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.listName);
    String newListName = listEditText.getText().toString();

    try {
        if(!listAction.listExist(newListName)){
            listAction.createList(newListName, "To Buy");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent viewListsIntent = new Intent(this, ItemListActivity.class);
    startActivity(viewListsIntent);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your issue has probably nothing to do with spinners. In the logcat, scroll down a bit and the line where the null pointer exception occurs will be indicated. Then just fix that null pointer bug.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm just starting development on Android and I'm still not familiar with the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `findViewById` *before* you set the view contents. You must move these lines

```
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.createlist);
```

to the top of your `onCreate` method. You probably think it has to do with Spinners because you added the Spinner code before these two lines.